# maximum coverage version of dominating set

Tags: graphs, np-complete, terminology, np-hard, set-cover

The dominating set problem is :

> Given an $n$ vertex graph $G=(V,E)$, find a set $S(\subseteq V)$ such that $|N[S]|$ is exactly $n$, where $$N[S] := \{x~ | \text{ either $x$ or a neighbor of $x$ lies in $S$}\}$$

My question is if the following (new problem) has a definite name in literature, and if not what should be the most appropriate name.

> **New Problem:** Given an $n$ vertex graph $G=(V,E)$ and an integer $k$ , find a set $S(\subseteq V)$ of size $k$ such that $|N[S]|$ is maximized.

For the second problem, some of the names I have seen in the literature are maximum-graph-coverage; partial-coverage; k-dominating-set, (however, the exact same names are also used in other contexts).

Comment: This problem is equivalent to the partial dominating set problem, where you need to find a dominating set that dominates a minimum number of vertices. You can binary search the number of vertices that can be covered by $k$ and solve the partial dominating set for each

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in which you must select $k$ vertices to maximize the number of vertices dominated is known as the *budgeted dominating set problem*. The problem or its connected variant is studied at least by Lamprou, Sigalis and Zissimopoulos [1] and Khuller, Purohit and Sarpatwar [2]. It also appears in the recent survey of Narayanaswamy and Vijayaragunathan [3].

---

[1] [Lamprou, Ioannis, Ioannis Sigalas, and Vassilis Zissimopoulos. "Improved Budgeted Connected Domination and Budgeted Edge-Vertex Domination." arXiv preprint arXiv:1907.06576 (2019).](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.06576.pdf)

[2] [Khuller, Samir, Manish Purohit, and Kanthi K. Sarpatwar. "Analyzing the optimal neighborhood: Algorithms for budgeted and partial connected dominating set problems." Proceedings of the twenty-fifth annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete algorithms. Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics, 2014.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2309)

[3] [Narayanaswamy, N. S., and R. Vijayaragunathan. "Parameterized Optimization in Uncertain Graphs—A Survey and Some Results." Algorithms 13.1 (2020): 3.](https://www.mdpi.com/1999-4893/13/1/3/pdf)